# Newline in constant in aspx page first line

Tags: c#, asp.net, newline, constants

The error says line 1 which is this piece of code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MovieReviews.aspx.cs" Inherits="MovieReviews" %>
```

I have searched the other problems with this error and none seem to be the same as mine. I cannot find out what is wrong with this code as is seems fine to me.

Comment: Looks like your .aspx page was served like a static content and it was not taken care by `asp.net engine`

Comment: Check for multiple script tags and also check you are not creating any Script tag from code behind

Comment: Are you running from visual studio or IIS?

Comment: Please provide more details.  What is the actual error message?  Stacktrace? What does `Newline` have to do with this?

Comment: I bet that it's an issue with a control being rendered on the page ...

Comment: Is this a web site, or web application?

Comment: Could you change **CodeFile** to **CodeBehind** and test it again? By the way, did you inherit the above code from Website Project?

Comment: Also, try fully qualifying your `Inherits` value with a namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have some weird line endings mixed up.

Try this: type in the full line character by character on a lower line, then delete all previous lines, that first one included, so that your hand-typed line becomes the first.

If the problem persists it may be due to magic bytes before the first character.

Are you doing some cross-platform work (linux/mac/windows)?